# Simple query, need help replacing some text

Tags: c#

I've got a login, and most of my users type in the following type of username "mydomain\Y98765" the to get into our website. I have recently upgraded our website, and no longer need them to type in the "mydomain\" within th username. I know I need to use the replace command to replace "mydomain\" with "", however, my server keeps crashing with my attempts. This is the code that works providing user has not typed in mydomain.

```
UserManager Usermanager = new UserManager();

UserData userdata = Usermanager.Login(UserName.Text, Password.Text, "DC=my,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk");
```

This is what I have attempted but crashes the server. Can someone help please

```
string username = UserName.Replace("mydomain\\","");
UserData userdata = Usermanager.Login(username, Password.Text, "DC=my,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk");
```

Comment: try `string username = UserName.Text.Replace(@"mydomain\","");`

Comment: Thanks Steveg89,that solves my initial query I think, need more testing though. Some of our newer users don't have "mydomain\" in their usernames, will this cope with that scenario?

Comment: This replacement code will do nothing if "myDomain\" is not found in the input string. It won't account for typos and things, but I wouldn't expect a login form to do that anyway. I've added an answer that explains why this fix works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve your secon dissue try:

```
string username = (UserName.Text.Contains("mydomain\\")) ? UserName.Text.Replace("mydomain\\","") : UserName.Text;
UserData userdata = Usermanager.Login(username, Password.Text, "DC=my,DC=domain,DC=co,DC=uk");
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your replacement code doesn't function is because you aren't actually using the text of the Username control. You're attempting to call replace on the control itself, which has no effect. To correct this, you must change your code to:

```
string username = UserName.Text.Replace(@"mydomain\","");
```

The check on whether the string contains "mydomain\" is unnecessary. Replace will not do anything to the string if it doesn't contain "mydomain\" and it won't really increase efficiency either way.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I thought that was the case, I was trying to follow intellisense and was getting errors when I had ".Text.Replace". Replace should not do anything if "mydomain\" did not exist, however I tried the same username/password combo, one with mydomain\ and one without and it refused to log me into the system with the one that was without... This cms I am working with is not the best at consistency...

Comment: Upvoted your answer as you answered the original question ;o)

Comment: Thanks. In my tests the replace did not alter the string when the "mydomain\" was not present. Are you 100% sure you didn't mistype the password or something?